# Debugging Post Request with Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to use Chrome Dev for debugging the following Angular post request :

```
$http.post("http://picjboss.puma.lan:8880/fluxpousse/api/flow/createOrUpdateHeader", flowHeader)
```

After running the statement with right-click / evaluate, I can see the post in the network panel with a pending state. How can I get the result or "commit" the request  and leave easily this "pending" state from the dev console ?

I am not yet very familiar with JS callbacks, some code is expected. Thanks.

EDIT

I have tried to run from the console :

```
$scope.$apply(function(){$http.post("http://picjboss.puma.lan:8880/fluxpousse/api/flow/createOrUpdateHeader", flowHeader).success(function(data){console.log("error "+data)}).error(function(data){console.log("error "+data)})})
```

It returns : undefined

EDIT

The error message returned is :
JBoss Web/2.1.3.GA - Rapport d'erreur

## Etat HTTP 400 -

**type** Rapport d'ï¿½tat

**message**

**description** La requï¿½te envoyï¿½e par le client ï¿½tait syntaxiquement incorrecte ().

#### JBoss Web/2.1.3.GA

EDIT
The post I am trying to solve generate an HTTP 400. Here is the result :

- Request URL:http://picjboss.puma.lan:8880/fluxpousse/api/flow/createOrUpdateHeader
  Request Method:POST
  Status Code:400 Mauvaise Requ?te
  Request Headersview source
  Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
  Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
  Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
  Connection:keep-alive
  Content-Length:5354
  Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
  Cookie:JSESSIONID=285AF523EA18C0D7F9D581CDB2286C56
  Host:picjboss.puma.lan:8880
  Origin:http://picjboss.puma.lan:8880
  Referer:http://picjboss.puma.lan:8880/fluxpousse/
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
  X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
  Request Payloadview source
  {refHeader:IDSFP, idEntrepot:619, codeEntreprise:null, codeBanniere:null, codeArticle:7,…}
  cessionPrice: 78
  codeArticle: "7"
  codeBanniere: null
  codeDateAppro: null
  codeDateDelivery: null
  codeDatePrepa: null
  codeEntreprise: null
  codeFournisseur: null
  codeUtilisateur: null
  codeUtilisateurLastUpdate: null
  createDate: null
  dateAppro: null
  dateDelivery: null
  datePrepa: null
  hasAssortControl: null
  hasCadenceForce: null
  idEntrepot: 619
  isFreeCost: null
  labelArticle: "Mayonnaise de DIJON"
  labelFournisseur: null
  listDetail: [,…]
  pcbArticle: 12
  pvc: 78
  qte: 78
  refCommande: "ref"
  refHeader: "IDSFP"
  state: "CREATED"
  stockArticle: 1200
  updateDate: null
  Response Headersview source
  Connection:close
  Content-Length:996
  Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
  Date:Fri, 08 Nov 2013 15:19:30 GMT
  Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
  X-Powered-By:Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1

Answer (score 1):

Each $http request should have success and error callback like this:

```
$http({method: 'POST', url: '/someUrl'}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
  // when the response is available
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
// called asynchronously if an error occurs
// or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Inside these methods you can debug in Dev Tools.

And if your request keeps pending, it might be something wrong with server side.

Note that if you don't have breakpoints making $http available (for example using Angular 1.2.6 in the chrome devtools) you can use:

```
angular.element(document).injector()
 .get('$http')({method: 'POST', url: '/someUrl'})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       console.log('$http-success:',arguments);
       debugger;
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       console.log('$http-error:',arguments);
       debugger;
    });
```

Comment: I have success/error in my final code. My requirement concerns only the console. If added : .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {console.log(data)}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {console.log(data)}) but it returns me a function and the request stay pending. How can I get data or error messages ?

Comment: If your request stay pending, it means it still didn't receive response from server (or request didn't even hit server). Can you debug server side somehow?

Comment: When I run my code directly out of debug context I get a HTTP 400 error. That is what I am trying to fix. From the server side code, developpers can't solve the problem. So I want to modify my request in different ways to make it working. But can't get the return callback with errors. This is my question. Thanks.

Comment: My request is pending just after evaluating my statement in chrome. If I run my code complety (without stop), at a certain moment (??) I can see a 400 in the network panel.

Comment: 1) Can you post now how your entire request looks like? 2) What if you put breakpoint in error callback?

Comment: This could mean your request is badly constructed and server can't handle it: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html... can you set data type into your request (and content-type as well), maybe server be able to handle it then...for this really there should be additional info from server